# PHP class for using like Java Action in Struts?

Tags: php

I'm 9 to 6 Java programer but in my spare time I have little proyects in PHP.
Just wondering what do you guys think of using this class and what security considerations I might have

```
class Action{

    var $func;
    var $param;

    function Action(){

        $url_keys = array_keys($_GET);
        $this->func = $url_keys[0];
        $this->param = $_GET[$this->func];
    }

    function callFunction(){
        $f = $this->func;
        $f( $this->param );
    }
}

$ajax = new Action();
$ajax-> callFunction();
```

I was thinking to using this including or extending another class.

```
http://localhost/proyect/object.php?update=1

include_once("class.Action.php");


function update($id){
 //the function
}
```

For the record I don't want to use a framework this proyect its to small :P

Comment: Try using Slim framework for PHP. It's good for small projects. http://www.slimframework.com/

Comment: thanks, i'm going to looking at this framework!! didn't know about this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all you should be working with php5 which has visibility keywords and some other things:

```
class Action {

    protected $func;
    protected $param;

    public function __construct($params = array()){

        $url_keys = array_keys($params);
        $this->func = $url_keys[0] . "Action"; // so use can not call function without surfix "Action" in this class
        $this->param = $params[$this->func];
    }

    public function callFunction(){
        $f = $this->func;
        return $f( $this->param );
    }
}
```

You should always pass in `$_GET` IMO so your instantiation now looks like this:

```
$action = new Action($_GET);
$action->callFunction();
```

Now as far as what youre trying to accomplish here it is unclear. If youre trying to essentially build a routing class i think this is pretty ugly and error prone as is.

In terms of you comment about not wanting to use a framework because the project is simple/small id urge you to check out  [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) or [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) micro frameworks instead of building from scratch.

For example with Silex:

```
$app = new Silex\Application(); 

$app->get('/object/update/{id}', function($id) use($app) { 
    // do your update with $id
    // then return a response

    return 'Update Complete';
    // basically you return whatever response you want so normally youd return html. 
}); 

$app->run();
```

Comment: you're missing security stuff here, I edited your code

Comment: @Bang: Wasnt missing anything. It wasnt in the original code and the only reason i put in that code block was to show the differenct in function and property definitions from php4 to php5. In fact i wouldnt recommend using what he has at all even with your edit :-)

Comment: b/c in the question he mention about security considerations so I think you should adding those in your answer

Comment: I didnt even read that part... distracted by the php4 nastiness.

Comment: prodigitalson thank for your help! i also thought that it might be error prone too... I better check those frameworks you mention... slim looks really what i was looking for!!